# Short story collection about were-creatures and shapeshifters

Tags: story-identification, werewolf, shape-shifter, anthology-book

I borrowed and read this book (in English) from a local library in Rancho Bernardo, California as a child in the early to mid 90's, no later than '96. The collection itself may have been written in the 80's or earlier. The cover of the book was a light green, and on the left side it had an image of a drawn tropical forest with animals in it; on the right side was the book's title and editor. Many of the stories were about werewolves, but the collection overall was about people turning into various animals. A couple of them stood out very powerfully:

1. A morbidly obese man who worked as an exhibit in a circus sideshow suddenly turns into an elephant and is locked up with the circus' elephants for the night; in the morning he is human again. This continues to happen every full moon night, and the man becomes famous for being the "smartest elephant in the world", making the circus famous.
2. A young man reaches adulthood and is inexplicably drawn to a river, where he turns into a salmon and joins the salmon mating run. His family works desperately to get him out of the water before he reaches the spawning grounds, where he will spawn and die like all of the other salmon. They succeed in getting him out of the water and conveying this information to him, telling him that if he can resist the urge he will live, but the instinct is too powerful and he leaps back into the water before they can stop him.

There were many other stories in this collection but these are two I remember the most about. I don't remember any author's names or the editor's name.

Comment: The elephant one is Jody Lynn Nye's "What, And Give Up Show Business" most likely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Otherwere: Stories of Transformation](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?25278)*

[image: Green cover of "Otherwer, stories of transformation" with a humanoid creatiure in a jungle setting]

> These masterful tales do not involve werewolves, butr a wonderfully diverse assortment of creatures including a serpent, a child, an elephant--even a right-wing Republican. Blending elements of fantasy, mystery, comedy and mythology, these extraordinary tales take lycanthropy into an entirely new realm.

The elephant story is Jody Lynn Nye's "What, And Give Up Show Business". I don't know which one the salmon story is, but [this reviewer](https://www.nesfa.org/reviews/Leeper/otherwer.html) mentions a were-salmon.

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's it! Thank you so much! I never expected it to be found this soon!

Comment: I lucked into an ebook copy of the elephant story. Please, if you would, accept the answer by clicking on the green checkmark. :) It give both of us points and it helps our metrics.

Comment: Done! Thanks again, you have no idea how long I've been looking for this! I just ordered it from Amazon, can't wait to read it again! I up-voted you too so thanks!

Comment: Peter David's story is tied to his novel, *Howling Mad*, about a wolf that turns into a human being under the full moon.